# Backbone fetch() always returns same model

Tags: jquery, rest, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

For some reason, my code is always returning the same model even though I can see that the correct id is being passed in after I select the item in a listView page.

```
// main.js (relavent function)

    venueDetails: function (id) {
        // here, id is correct
        var venue = new Venue({_id: id});
        venue.fetch({success: function(){
            // here, the id of venue is changed for some reason
            console.log(venue.id);
            $("#content").html(new VenueView({model: venue}).el);
        }});
        this.headerView.selectMenuItem();
    },
```

The model,

```
// model.js (relavent model)

    var base = 'http://localhost:3000';

    window.Venue = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: base+"/venues",
        idAttribute: "_id",
    });

    window.VenueCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Venue,
        url: base+"/venues?populate=true"
    });
```

In the picture, you can see where the model.id is different from whats in the url
[image]

EDIT: added router mapping

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

```
routes: {
    ""                     : "home",
    <!-- venues -->
    "venues"               : "venueList",
    "venues/page/:page"    : "venueList",
    "venues/add"           : "addVenue",
    "venues/:id"           : "venueDetails",
```

Comment: Are you seeing the proper GET call and response? Try with the net panel in firebug.

Comment: hmm, by the time it makes a request to the server api, it's passing in the incorrect id. Is there some method that I should override to see where it might be replacing the id?

Comment: just use console.log(venue.id) after the model initialization. Is it printing the wrong id? Also paste the router mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the `_id` attribute is being accessed correctly in the model, since `venue.fetch` seems to be making a call out to some type of default.

Maybe try:

```
   window.Venue = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: base+"/venues",
        idAttribute: this.options._id,
    });
```

(and pull the id from the options hash)

And if that doesn't work, try declaring the `idAttribute` dynamically:

```
   window.Venue = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: base+"/venues",
        idAttribute: function() { return this.options._id },
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that bit of code quite late at night, I've corrected it to be this.options

Answer (score 1):

This

```
 var base = 'http://localhost:3000';
```

is a bad idea, and completely unnecessary. Just get rid of that entirely. Just use absolute paths (like '/venues') as URLs and your app will work properly no matter where it's running.

Between your code and screenshot there are 2 different ports. Are you sure you are talking to the right application server?

Otherwise, have you checked your server side code for a bug? It could be something as simple as the server side code is using the wrong value when querying the database.

Comment: right now, the api is hosted separately from the UI application. that's why I have this full url in there - and they are on different ports. I'm new to backbone so if there is a better way, I'm all ears!

Comment: ok, i went ahead and merged the ui application into the api project to simplify things. I still get the same result where the wrong model is fetched.

Comment: UGH! my server side code DID have a bug. I'm using Mongoose and was using findOne() instead of findById(). thanks